# Installing a 3rd party radio in a VW Polo

Tags: electrical, vw, audio, polo

I am finding it hard to understand why I need run a 12v wire as well as use a Quadlock to ISO converter.  The current VW radio clearly gets power from its connector and is able to tell if the engine is running.  Yet the converter leads need to be connected to 12V power as well as the Quadlock.

Comment: It does seem odd.  What year of Polo is it and what model of radio are you fitting?

Comment: Thank u for sharing Ian
I am having a similar problem which suspect has the solution u suggest
Did yours work after the additional 12v